# How to call a js_of_ocaml method?

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

I have a one-line js_of_ocaml program:

```
Dom_html.window##scroll 100 100 ;
```

Which fails with the error:

```
File "tests/test_scrolling.ml", line 2, characters 0-23:
Error: This expression has type int -> int -> unit Js.meth
       but an expression was expected of type < get : 'a; .. > Js.gen_prop
Command exited with code 2.
```

How do I call this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.5/manual/library) the method invocation has the following syntax:

```
        obj : <m : t_1 -> ... -> t_n -> u meth; ..> Js.t
            e_i : t_i               (1 <= i <= n)
        -------------------------------------------------
                  obj##m(e_1, ..., e_n) : u
```

That means, to me, that methods should be called in uncurryied form, i.e.,

```
Dom_html.window##scroll(100, 100)
```